# Disable caching for the front page

Tags: 8, hooks, caching

How can I disable caching for the front page, programmatically?

Comment: Assuming the page cache?

Comment: yes assuming page cache

Answer (score 2):

I think one way to achieve that is by altering `'<front>'` route with a RouteSubscriber service.

```
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    arguments: ['@config.factory']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Then in your RouteSubscriber.php class :

```
/**
 * Event subscriber.
 */

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Subscribe to KernelEvents::REQUEST events and redirect if user is press.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase  {

    protected $configFactory;

    /**
     * RouteSubscriber constructor.
     * @param ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory
     */
    public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
        $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        if ($route_front = $collection->get('<front>')) {
            $route_front->setOption('no_cache', TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```